# Why do the components of the metric contain basis vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vectors, transformation, tensors

[image]

I'm learning about the transformation rules for vectors. In the image above, the author addresses that the components of the metric transform covariantly. However, I'm confused as to why the metric components comprise base vectors in this explanation. Aren't the components the differentials $dx^a$ and $dx^b$?

The full link is [here](http://astro.dur.ac.uk/~done/gr/l2.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren’t the components. In local coordinates, the metric takes the form $$g=\sum\limits_{i,j} g_{ij}dx^i\otimes dx^j.$$ Note that the components are $g_{ij}=g\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right)$.

Remember that, in general, if we have a representation of a vector in a given basis, the components are given by the dual basis acting on that vector.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but is it true that if the components are the dual basis, would the components of the dual vectors be made up of the basis from the original vector space, due to duality?

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: Thank you. Back to my original question: So, what is the rule for the transformation of the metric tensor's components?

Comment: @Shocked they transform covariantly.

Comment: Can you walk through why the components of this tensor transform covariantly? It's tough to find literature online, and the above explanation doesn't make sense.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to see this. One way is that it's encoded in the bilinearity. That is to say, if we have a bilinear map $f:V\times V\rightarrow \mathbb{R},$ then its coordinates will transform covariantly. Another is to calculate the Jacobian (check out this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor#Coordinate_transformations), which explicitly shows it. You may also like this link: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/159492/tensors-as-multilinear-maps